# Waiting on file to be written in bash?

Tags: bash, shell

I have the following code:

```
while [ ! -f testfile.p ]
do
    sleep 1
    echo "working"
done
```

When I do `ls`, I see that testfile.p exists. Yet, this doesn't work. The loop never ends. When I try and test it with the following code:

```
[ ! -f testfile.p ] && echo "exists" || echo "doesn't exist"
```

all I get is "doesn't exist".

Any thoughts on what could be wrong or how to trouble shoot this?

Comment: `testfile.p` probably isn't a regular file.  Is it a directory, socket, or special device?

Comment: if `testfile.p` is a regular file, `[ ! -f testfile.p ]` evals false, so `doesn't exist` should be printed. your testing is problematic, as well as your question.

Comment: Your test code is backward - it'll echo exists when it doesn't and vice versa.

Comment: if you ever tried `help test`, you should see the proper test for your request should be `-e` or `-a`.

Comment: It may be something as simple as your script with the `while` loop running in the wrong directory.

Comment: try with `test` check if this file or not
 
`test -f testfile.p
if [ $? -eq 0 ];
then
echo "file"
else
echo "not a file"
fi`

Comment: Ahhhh thanks. I have it all backwards.

Comment: Still have problems. Running the tests suggested above confirm the file is int he directory. If the file is in the directory when I start the script, it recognizes it and the while loop doesn't run. If it's not in the directory, the while loop shows it's working, and then when I copy the file to the directory, it doesn't recognize it. What gives? UPDATE: It does find my file once I paste it in the folder. But it takes a good 15-20 seconds before it recognizes it. That's odd.

Comment: @user1566200 forget test now with while loop you can check if file or not with while loop example :
`while [ -e file ];
do
echo "exist"
done`

`-e` denotes  exist or not you can check `-d` directory or not `-f` file or not if you want to break the loop you can add `break` after `echo`